# Makefile not working, path not found to 'make' command

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

Im a first year university student learning how to use makefiles to compile and run my simple program. I set it up as instructed but when i type in "make" it pops up this error:

The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

Tried checking the path and uninstalled and reinstalled minGW using the installer. Should i try installing the gcc compiler a different way? Please keep in mind im pretty new to this stuff. Using C btw.

Comment: It seems you're running Windows. Have you installed `make`? Have you added its location to the system `PATH`? If you have installed `make`, *how* did you install it? Are you really using MinGW?

Comment: I honestly thought make would be apart of MinGW and the gcc compiler, thanks for pointing it out, i got it to work!

Answer (score 1):

MinGW is just the compiler tools. But usually it comes with `mingw32-make`.

So you would try that, but the location of the MinGW .exe files you are trying to run must be in the PATH environment variable or it won't find them.

If you want to run make like they do on Linux/Unix I recommend you install MSYS2 shell from https://www.msys2.org/

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

Use `mingw32-make` instead of `make` after installing `mingw`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have "make" command follow steps; 
(First, make sure you have installed choco)

- Run PowerShell as administrator
- choco install make